# Does a Linq expression treat a group specially when iterating it with the 'from' clause?

Tags: .net, linq, linq-group

Consider this query to group a list of students by the 1st letter of their last name:

```
var query = from s in students
            group s by s.Last[0] into group1
            orderby group1.Key
            from g in group1
            select new { g.First, g.Last }
```

Now, the part that says `from g in group1` is not iterating through the keys of `group1`, it's iterating through the values of each key in `group1`.

This is how I'd like it to be handled (to produce a flat list), but it seems counter intuitive to me.

To answer my question, I just need someone to point me to the part of MSDN that explains this or explain why I'm the counter intuitive one ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you introduce a secondary `from` clause in a query expression, that translates into a call to [`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345618). As you say, that's basically a flattening operation.

It may make it easier to convert it into two queries:

```
var groups = from s in students
             group s by s.Last[0];

var query = from grp in groups
            orderby grp.Key
            from item in grp
            select new { item.First, item.Last };
```

This is exactly equivalent to the original query you've got, but you *may* find it easier to understand.

Other resources which may help... where [Edulinq](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/tags/Edulinq/default.aspx) is a series of blog posts I wrote, reimplementing LINQ to Objects from scratch for educational purposes.

- [LINQ Query Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397676.aspx) (MSDN)
- [Edulinq part 9 - `SelectMany`](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/12/27/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-9-selectmany.aspx)
- [Edulinq part 41 - how query expressions work](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/01/28/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-41-how-query-expressions-work.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Jon, your 'SelectMany' document makes it clear. I prefer learning from first principles so the whole guide should suit me.